# Survey on homological stability

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, group-cohomology, textbook-recommendation

Background: homological stability is the phenomenon that for many natural families of groups $G_0 \to G_1 \to G_2 \to \dots$, the group homology $H_i(G_n)$ stabilizes for $n \gg i$. This is e.g. the case for symmetric groups, braid groups, general linear groups, mapping class groups of surfaces, automorphisms of free groups, etc. This even generalizes to many natural families of topological spaces, e.g. unordered configuration spaces (with special case $BG_n$ above). There's also representation stability and other closely related phenomena.

I'm preparing an introductory talk on topic and I'd like to include historical context. While I think I've covered most of the bases, I'd like to make sure I haven't missed anything (I'm not necessarily an expert on all this).

While many recent strides have happened in this field, there are also a lot of older results – originating in Quillen's 1973 paper, as far as I know. I have found a lot of current research on this topic, and I could theoretically follow all the references and build back the tree, but this would be very time consuming. Is there any general survey that would recall, explain, and put in historical context these results?

Comment: Ralph Cohen has a survey for moduli spaces: https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.1938. Being a decade old though, it naturally lacks some recent developments. For instance the first Church-Farb rep-stability paper came out a year later.

Comment: There are now a number of introductions and surveys on homological stability, though none of them claim to give a complete historical account: Wahl (https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.07767), Jimenez-Rolland--Wilson (https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.04096), and myself (https://www.utsc.utoronto.ca/people/kupers/wp-content/uploads/sites/50/homstab.pdf).